# Flutter 2.10 firebase - Sending notifications from device to device android and IOS

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I see many "similar" questions but none has clear or updated answers, especially for the new gen of flutter and firebase

I have a delivery app, where delivery man can update package to "delivered", once he update it I want to send notification to package owner that it was delivered.

what is the best way to gain the required? how to send notification from one device to another device ?

Im developing in flutter and firebase

All Tutorials I found talks about sending through firebase itself

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you can send a notification directly to another user. You send it to Firebase, then firebase sends it to another user, or you use a Cloud Function where you send the user Id to which you need to send the notification, and the Cloud Function looks up the user from that id, grabs its registered device token, then sends it to that user's device, since the notifications are based on a registered device token - you shouldn't know the device token of the other person, you may know their user Id, so yes - you still need Firebase.

Comment: I agree, I need firebase either way, but I though if there is anyway to make firebase once delivery man update package, then update firestore accordingly, then send the notification, but as I understood from you, I must use cloud functions for that ? (to listen to firestore chanegs) and not healthy to save tokenID in package owner firestore documentation ?

Comment: You got it. The delivery man never sends it directly. He sends it to firestore, cloud function listens to the change, sends it to the person. Every package owner must have their device token id associated to their unique user Id. They can have more than one device token (a phone, tablet, desktop).

Comment: I see your point, thanks!!!
The issue is the cloud functions are only by paying for package and im in early developments of it. thought might be some free options for testing only. but will keep posted once I do it. thanks again

Comment: Sure. But you know that Cloud Functions has a pay-as-you-go that’s practically free because they don’t charge you anything if you don’t exceed the 2m invocations a month (which I doubt you will) which will serve your purposes without breaking the bank. Think about it.

Comment: Yes I just noticed it! thats great (it wont for sure :) ) thanks man